# How to do I send an email a target group based on stored procedure @Error message?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Please forgive me for asking too many questions.

I have been working on this all day and can't take it anymore.

I have a stored proc called sp_signup()

The stored proc first checks to see if the user has already signed up. If yes, then inform the user that s/he has already signed up for this class.

```
SET @ERROR = 'You have already signed up for this training'
```

This works a treat.

If no, then check to see if there are still available seats.

If seats are still available, sign the user up by inserting into training table and inform the user s/her has been signed up.

```
 SET @ERROR = 'You have been registered for this class'
```

This works a treat.

If no seats remain, then put the user on waiting list by inserting the user's registration info into waitingList table and inform the user s/he has been placed on waiting list.

```
SET @ERROR = 'Sorry, but this class is full. However, you have been placed on waiting list.'
```

This works a treat as well.

So, the stored proc, when tested, works great.

However, on our .net app that calls the stored proc, we are sending users emails informing them that they have either been signed up for the class or have been placed on waiting list depending on what the @Error message says.

This is where we are having problem because the email is not going out.

Here are the conditionals for sending email:

```
If Label1.Text = "You have been registered for this class" Then
'Email code goes here and is sent to inform users they have been registered for class
ElseIf Label1.Text = "Sorry, but this class is full. However, you have been placed on waiting list." Then
'Email code goes here and is sent inform to users they have been placed on waiting list
Else

End If
```

below is where the stored procedure call is made:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Dim username = Session("Username")

Try

    Dim s As String

    s = "sp_signup"
    Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(s, conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cosID", Request.QueryString("cosId"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locID", Request.QueryString("locid"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat", Request.QueryString("iddate"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ERROR", SqlDbType.[Char], 500)
    cmd.Parameters("@ERROR").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    message = DirectCast(cmd.Parameters("@ERROR").Value, String)
    Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", conn)
    Dim skey As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()
    Session("TrainingId") = skey
    conn.Close()
    btnSendEmail_Click()

    'Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was processed
    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
    Label1.Text = message

Catch

    'If the message failed at some point, let the user know
    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    Label1.Text = message

End Try
End Sub
```

The email code has been tested and works without the stored proc and is below:

```
Protected Sub btnSendEmail_Click()
    Dim skey As Integer = Session("TrainingId")
    'Response.Write(skey)
    'Response.End()
    Dim Conn As SqlConnection
    'Dim param As SqlParameter
    'Dim cmdcommand As SqlCommand
    Conn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Conn.Open()

    If Label1.Text = "You have been registered for this class" Then
        Dim emailcmd As New SqlCommand("select distinct lg.Email, lg.fullname, c.CourseName, l.location, d.trainingDates, d.trainingTime, i.instructorName from tblTrainings t Inner Join tblCourses c on t.courseId = c.courseId " & _
                                               " Inner Join tblLocations l on t.locationId = l.LocationId " & _
                                               " Inner Join tblTrainingDates d on t.dateid=d.dateid " & _
                                               " Inner Join tblCourseInstructor ic on c.courseId = ic.CourseId " & _
                                               " Inner Join tblInstructors i on ic.instructorId = i.instructorId " & _
                                               " Inner Join tblLogin lg on t.username = lg.username where lg.username = '" & Session("username") & "' AND t.CourseID = " & Request.QueryString("cosId") & "  AND t.LocationID = " & Request.QueryString("locid") & " AND t.dateId = " & Request.QueryString("iddate") & " AND TrainingId = " & skey & ";", Conn)
        Dim dr = emailcmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.Read() Then
            email = dr.GetString(0)
            fullname = dr.GetString(1)
            courses = dr.GetString(2)
            Loc = dr.GetString(3)
            tdates = dr.GetDateTime(4)
            ttime = dr.GetString(5)
        End If
        'code for other email requests
        Dim objSmtpClient As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("relay.smtp", 25)
        Dim objSender As MailAddress = New MailAddress("name.emailadd.com", "name.emailadd.com")
        Dim objMail As MailMessage = New MailMessage("name.emailadd.com", "name.emailadd.com")
        objMail.Bcc.Add("name.emailadd.com")
        objMail.To.Add(email)
        'objMail.CC.Add("name.emailadd.com")
        objMail.Subject = "About Your Training: " & courses & ""
        objMail.Body = " Dear " & fullname & " <br>You have just signed up for <b>" & courses & "</b> training. <br><br>This training will be held at <b>" & Loc & "</b> on <b>" & tdates & "</b> starting from <b>" & ttime & "</b>.<br><br> For more details about this training, please visit <a href='Training/'> Training/</a>. "
        objMail.IsBodyHtml = True
        objSmtpClient.Send(objMail)
        dr.Close()
    ElseIf Label1.Text = "Sorry, but this class is full. However, you have been placed on waiting list." Then
        Dim waitcmd As New SqlCommand("select distinct lg.Email, lg.fullname, c.CourseName, wl.location, d.trainingDates, d.trainingTime, i.instructorName from tblWaitingList wl Inner Join tblCourses c on wl.courseId = c.courseId " & _
                                   " Inner Join tblLocations l on wl.locationId = l.LocationId " & _
                                   " Inner Join tblTrainingDates d on wl.dateid=d.dateid " & _
                                   " Inner Join tblCourseInstructor ic on c.courseId = ic.CourseId " & _
                                   " Inner Join tblInstructors i on ic.instructorId = i.instructorId " & _
                                   " Inner Join tblLogin lg on wl.username = lg.username where lg.username = '" & Session("username") & "' AND wl.CourseID = " & Request.QueryString("cosId") & "  AND wl.LocationID = " & Request.QueryString("locid") & " AND wl.dateId = " & Request.QueryString("iddate") & " AND TrainingId = " & skey & ";", Conn)
        Dim dr = waitcmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.Read() Then
            email = dr.GetString(0)
            fullname = dr.GetString(1)
            courses = dr.GetString(2)
            Loc = dr.GetString(3)
            tdates = dr.GetDateTime(4)
            ttime = dr.GetString(5)
        End If
        'code for other email requests
        Dim objSmtpClient As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("relay.smtp", 25)
        Dim objSender As MailAddress = New MailAddress("name.emailadd.com", "name.emailadd.com")
        Dim objMail As MailMessage = New MailMessage("name.emailadd.com", "name.emailadd.com")
        objMail.Bcc.Add("name.emailadd.com")
        objMail.To.Add(email)
        'objMail.CC.Add("name.emailadd.com")
        objMail.Subject = "About Your Training: " & courses & ""
        objMail.Body = " Dear " & fullname & " <br>You have been placed on the waiting list for <b>" & courses & "</b> training. <br><br>This training will be held at <b>" & Loc & "</b> on <b>" & tdates & "</b> starting from <b>" & ttime & "</b>.<br><br> Should a seat become available, notification will be based on first-come, first-served bases.<br>For more details about this training, please visit <a href='http://#/'> http://Training/</a>. "
        objMail.IsBodyHtml = True
        objSmtpClient.Send(objMail)
        dr.Close()
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So where is the code for the btnSendEmail_Click() method?

Comment: @Karl, thank you sir for responding.

I have updated code above

Comment: If you debug the btnSendEmail_Click method, does it correctly fall into the If or ElseIf? My question is, is the problem with matching the string value of the "error" from the initial query or is the problem with getting the email address from the subsequent query logic?

Comment: @Karl,

First if I debug: 
Label1.Text, I get the correct values.

Also, if remove the IF statements from email sub, the email goes out each time record is inserted into the db.

Problem was that it sends the same message to users informing them they had successfully signed up for a class whether the user signed of for training or was placed in watinglist.

Comment: Leave the IF/ELSEIF logic in there, but I just wanted to make sure it was actually find a truthful value for either the IF or the ELSEIF. So my question is, if you debug and the IF is true (user was successfully registerd for the class), then is the wrong email message sent or no email sent at all?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the order of the following statements wrong:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ...
    btnSendEmail_Click()
    ...
    Label1.Text = message
```

I think you should set `Label1.Text` before calling `btnSendEmail_Click()`. It should be the other way round:

```
    Label1.Text = message
    ...
    btnSendEmail_Click()
```

Comment: hi @M4N. I chhanged it like you said but no difference.

`            message = DirectCast(cmd.Parameters("@ERROR").Value, String)
            conn.Close()

            'Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was processed
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
            Label1.Text = message
            btnSendEmail_Click()
        Catch

            'If the message failed at some point, let the user know
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            Label1.Text = message

        End Try`